How would I enable Skia Graphite and Vulkan here?
To preface, this is a lot of info. I checked my GPU stats, and Skia and Vulkan are disabled. This is what it shows.
Graphics feature status:

Canvas: Hardware accelerated
Canvas out-of-process rasterization: Enabled
Direct Rendering Display Compositor: Disabled
Compositing: Hardware accelerated
Multiple Raster Threads: Disabled
OpenGL: Enabled
Rasterization: Hardware accelerated on all pages
Raw Draw: Disabled
Skia Graphite: Disabled
Video Decode: Hardware accelerated
Video Encode: Hardware accelerated
Vulkan: Disabled
WebGL: Hardware accelerated
WebGL2: Hardware accelerated
WebGPU: Hardware accelerated
WebNN: Disabled
this is from chrome://gpu


I want to preferably activate from the command line, I'm using the latest ubuntu version

How did you check this? What do you want to achieve?

I want to enable skia graphics in my Chromebook. I tried using chrome://flags and it didn’t work

The relevant commandline flags:
--enable-features=Vulkan
--enable-features=SkiaGraphite
If using WebGPU, at present you may also need --enable-unsafe-webgpu.
